# Aiogram with re

Tags: python, python-re, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(AdminFilter(), state="get price",
                    regexp=re.compile(r"^[0-9]*\|.*\|[0-9]*"))
async def get_price(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    m = message.text
    id = re.findall(r"^0[0-9]*", m)
    name = re.findall(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*₽$", m)
    cost = re.findall(r"^[0-9]*0$", m)
    await message.answer(
        f"""Товар добавлен:
        id: {id[0]}
        name: {name}
        cost: {cost}
    """)
```

I need this handler to catch messages in the id|name|cost format and then assign the values of id, name, cost to different variables

Answer (score 1):

You should use [regex capturing groups](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups) to be able to extract values and get them in your handler later, so you don't have to parse incoming text again.

Also, [aiogram](/questions/tagged/aiogram) can pass filter result into your handler if your handler "requests" this by requiring additional argument corresponding to the filter. Most built-in filters are configured to pass their results, [including regexp filter](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/5bcbcedebad98ccae0f8bd1c97c81fb2e05041e9/aiogram/dispatcher/filters/builtin.py#L435-L436), which passes `re.Match` object as `regexp` argument.

So, you should change your code to something like this:

```
@dp.message_handler(AdminFilter(), state="get price",
                    regexp=re.compile(r"^([0-9]*)\|(.*)\|([0-9]*)"))
async def get_price(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext, regexp: re.Match):
    id_ = regexp[1]  # note that it's still `str` even if you're capturing only digits
    name = regexp[2]
    cost = regexp[3]
    await message.answer(
        f"""Товар добавлен:
        id: {id_}
        name: {name}
        cost: {cost}
    """)
```

---

See also:

- [Python 3 `re.Match` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#match-objects)
- [Regular expressions interactive tutorial](https://regexone.com/)